# JSP BufferedReader how to search for a string in text file

Tags: jsp, bufferedreader

This is my running code so far it prints No Results Found!
I'd like to my code to fetch the text from the search text field name="criteria"
and be used to search for that record in the .txt file.

```
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container form-group panel panel-default">
    <%
        String inpt = request.getParameter("criteria");
        String jspPath = "D:\\TextDB\\";
        String fileName = "Student_Details.txt";
        String txtFilePath = jspPath + fileName;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilePath));
        //BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txtFilePath));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                if(line.equals(inpt))
                {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
            }
       out.println(sb.toString());
           if(line == null)
           {
            out.println("\n No Results Found!");        
           }
    %>
```

Comment: instead of "equals", have you tried "contains" on line "line.equals" . as equals might be checking exact values.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /Reader.jsp at line 35

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /Reader.jsp at line 35

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Reader.jsp at line 35

32:             String line;
33:     
34:     while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
35:      if(line.contains(inpt))
36:      {
37:       sb.append(line+"\n");
38:

Comment: contains reports an error

Comment: @jeetendraMandal if you have a working code please post it

Comment: if the File is correctly placed in the path you specified in your code it should work. File file = new File("G:\\test_line.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    String input = "test3";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     
     if(line.contains(input))
     {
      System.out.println("hello world test:"+line);
     }
     stringBuffer.append(line);
     stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as designed. You will *always* print 'No results found', because `line` will always be null at the end of the read loop. You should be testing `sb.length()` or whatever it is, not `line`.

NB 'No results found' is not valid HTML.

Comment: i don't think you got the problem right, it says "fetch the text from the search text field name="criteria" and be used to search for that record in the .txt file". your answer is not what was asked

Comment: @jeetendraMandal The problem is, and I quote, 'it prints "No Results Found!"', and I have both identified why and provided a solution. The OP's  code *does* correctly search for text in a file: it just misreports the results.